# Query to Order Number of Records through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, :as => :person
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I want to run a `Location` where clause. I then want to order the query so that the locations that has the most people associated with it is first, then goes down in descending order.

```
Location.where(place: "Waffle House")#Some query attached to this, but what do I write?
```

How can I write this query? Is it possible?

SOLVED: Solved the solution. Although hacky it works for now until I can create a SQL statement. Basically looped through the selected locations, counted the people for each location and added a virtual attribute with the person count and ordered the array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Active Record Guide section on conditional joins, should point you in the right direction.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: It's putting me in the right direction but I don't think it's what I need. I have a list of `Location` queries and I need to order it based on how many people are associated with each `Location`.

Comment: If it's too complex for the API to do it easily, you can just write it in plain SQL http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Location.joins("(
  SELECT person_id location_id, COUNT(1) people_count
  FROM people
  WHERE person_type = 'Location'
  GROUP BY person_id
  ) a ON a.location_id = locations.id"
).order("a.people_count DESC")
```